# What type of vulnerabilty is this?

Tags: vulnerability, denial-of-service, url, validation

I'm testing a website:

```
https://this-site.com/path/to/dirs
```

but what i've found is if I do the following below the site will load 4 pages in a infinite loop

```
https://this-site.com/path/to/dirs/.../.
```

I was thinking it would be something along the lines of some sort of input validation issue or even DOS as if I open up many tabs I could consume a great part of resources of that server. I've checked through google but I couldn't find anything related to what i've found .

Comment: "will load 4 pages in a infinite loop" - what do you exactly mean by this? Is it redirecting from one page to another in 4 separate requests?

Comment: Hi @tungsten, it redirects from one page to another in separate request .

Comment: it might be a user experience in which the site is traversing all the underlying directories backwards in separate steps(that may contain different index.html's), the question is what was the final page you saw? blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not any sort of vulnerability; simply a usability issue that might affect users visiting the site from a malformed URL.

It is not an easy way to perform a DOS attack, because there is no evidence that this is taking any more resources on the server than hitting non-redirecting set of pages, or preventing other users from accessing different pages.  You can set your browser to visit this redirect loop, but you can also use scripting tools or browser extensions to request any other page on the site repeatedly.  This is a flood attack, and does not depend on any vulnerability on the server.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense . I guess you can theoretically create a script to do the same .